# Changing Conv2dTranspose Output Shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I am creating a CVAE using convd2d and conv2dtranspose. When using conv2dtranspose I cannot replicate the encoder, as the shape dimension is odd and not even. I have searched how to do this but I cannot find anything useful that works. I have added and removed different stride lengths, and adjusted padding, however it did not work. I have attached the encoder and decoder below, with their respective model summaries. The main problem is in conv2d_transpose1 where the output shape is (None, 64, 4, 32) when it should be (None, 64, 3, 32)

```
    self.latent_dim = 6
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same'),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same'),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same'),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
            # No activation
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim + latent_dim),

        ]
    )


    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(latent_dim,)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16 * 1 * 64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
            tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(16, 1, 64)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu',),
            # No activation
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same'),
        ]
    )

    Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 6, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 3, 32)         9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 2, 64)         18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 1, 64)         36928     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                65600     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 12)                780       
=================================================================
Total params: 131,372
Trainable params: 131,372
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              7168      
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 16, 1, 64)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTran (None, 32, 2, 64)         36928     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 64, 4, 32)         18464     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTr (None, 128, 8, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 8, 1)         289       
=================================================================
Total params: 72,097
Trainable params: 72,097
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

Conv2DTranspose with a stride of 2 doubles the first two dimensions, so an input of (None, 32, 2, 32) is producing and output of shape (None, 64, 4, 32) and not (None, 64, 3, 32)